# How to insert an absolute input box and select menu inside table

Tags: html, html-table, cell

Right now I have input box on top of my select menu, but when I put those two inside my table it doesn't insert into the cell of the table but on top of it.

When I change the position to Relative it will insert to the cell  but the select menu won't show up.

Here is my html:

```
<table width="65%" >
<tr>
<td width="30%">machineID</td>
<td width="35%">

<input id="txtTest1" type="text" style="width:200px;POSITION: absolute">
<select id="ddlTest" onchange="document.getElementById('txtTest1').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text" style="width:217px;CLIP: rect(auto auto auto 200px); POSITION: absolute">
<!--<option>tt</option>
<option>dd</option> -->
</select>
</td>
<td width="35%">
<input id="txtTest2" type="text" style="width:200px;POSITION: absolute">
<select id="ddlTest2" onchange="document.getElementById('txtTest2').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text" style="width:217px;CLIP: rect(auto auto auto 200px); POSITION: absolute">   
</select>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That is how position absolute works. Why use tables then? Or position the table

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle for you and its working fine with position relative. http://jsfiddle.net/4fwbcozL/

Comment: but now the select menu is separated from the input box, I want my input box on top of the select menu so it looks like a select menu with input box